# How to handle ISR callbacks when writing a Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL)?

Tags: abstraction, drivers

I'm writing a Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) to abstract a hardware peripheral on an mcu.

The driver peripheral looks like this.

Driver module. Includes `hal.h`

```
void drv_init(void);
void drv_set(int x);
int drv_get(void);
void ISR_Handler(void);
// impmenets hal_ functions ...
```

Driver modules includes `hal.h` implements `hal_` functions and wraps inside them the `drv_` functions. When high level modules includes `hal.h` it actually calls drivers wrappers.

Hardware Abstraction Layer. Provides header only (interface) and includes none.

```
void hal_init(void);
void hal_set(int x);
int hal_get(void);
```

High Level module. Includes `hal.h`

```
void hl_init(void);
void hl_foo(void);
void hl_bar(void);
void hl_foo_bar_func(void);
```

Here's my problem.
`hl_foo_bar_func` must be called withing driver's `ISR_Handler`.
How can I do that?

I see only two ways of doing that.
Add `hal_set_isr_callback` that would take a pointer to a function set another pointer to a function that is called within driver's `ISR_Handler`.

Or... I can just add a `hal_isr_callback` that will be implemented inside high level module but that seems kind of ugly solution cause I'd have some functions implemented in driver module and one single function implemented in higher level modules.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If ISR_Handler must call hl_foo_bar_func then why doesn't ISR_Handler simply call hl_foo_bar_func?

Comment: Why not the callback? I would even add a queue in between so that the high level function doesn't run in isr mode